# Issue with Query Response sent to view - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am pretty new to Rails. I've a two controllers Users and Posts. Show method of User controller is as follows.

**users_controller.rb**

```
def show 
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

**show.html.erb**

```
<p>
  <strong>First Name:</strong>
  <%= @user.first_name %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Last Name :</strong>
  <%= @user.last_name %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Age :</strong>
  <%= @user.age %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Created At</strong>
  <%= @user.created_at %>
</p>

<h3> All Posts By <%= @user.first_name %> </h3>

 <%= @user.posts.each do |post| %>

    <li> <%= post.post_desc %> </li><br/>

 <% end %>
```

Everything goes fine as per the code, but query response is also appended like this. [stack_ques_reference_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5kQd.png)

If you see the image below is appended

```
[#<Post id: 2, user_id: 2, created_at: "2016-05-08 17:39:39", updated_at: "2016-05-08 17:39:39", post_desc: "Another post">, #<Post id: 3, user_id: 2, created_at: "2016-05-08 17:39:50", updated_at: "2016-05-08 17:39:50", post_desc: "Another post just to show post">, #<Post id: 9, user_id: 2, created_at: "2016-05-09 09:58:54", updated_at: "2016-05-09 09:58:54", post_desc: "Hello oye">, #<Post id: 10, user_id: 2, created_at: "2016-05-09 10:00:04", updated_at: "2016-05-09 10:00:04", post_desc: "Yummy Post by faizan">]
```

Any pointer to the solution and reason for this issue will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing array of objects

```
<%= @user.posts.each do |post| %>

    <li> <%= post.post_desc %> </li><br/>

 <% end %>
```

Just run each on the array by 
`<%= @user.posts.each do |post| %>` replacing with 
 `<% @user.posts.each do |post| %>`

```
 <% @user.posts.each do |post| %>

    <li> <%= post.post_desc %> </li><br/>

 <% end %>
```

Comment: My bad.Thanks for the response. It resolved the issue.